# How can I sell articles about TV shows online?

Tags: creative-writing, blog, freelance

I am a writer, and I write mostly articles about tv shows. How can I sell them?

I researched the freelance content marketplace, but I mostly just found the general sites like fiverr, freelancer, odesk etc. The only site I could find that specializes in content buying & selling articles is [thebestarticles.net](http://www.thebestarticles.net/?se).

Are there any other sites like this? Am I even looking for the right kind of place to sell my articles?

Comment: Welcome to Writers! Can you be more specific about what you want to do? What kind of content do you want to sell?

Comment: Also, I'd like to point out that a very short question by a new user that contains a link to a fairly random, relatively unknown website looks pretty spammy. Looking at your questions elsewhere on the network, I suspect that this is a genuine question, but adding to the question will help avoid that appearance and help avoid having this flagged as spam by users.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your suggestions. I really don't know that. I just researched for the freelance content marketplace, but I just found the general one like fiverr, freelancer, odesk etc. That the only one specializes in the content buying & selling was that one, so I wanted to ask is there anything alike this.

Comment: By the way, I write mostly articles about tv shows. So I wanted to sell them.

Comment: I've edited your question to emphasize the how of your question, rather than just ask for likely sites to sell articles on. I think this will get you more answers here. Does my edit work for you? Please revert my edit if I've missed what you're looking for.

Comment: There are many different sites that claim to pay you for blogging. Here are 2 links: [https://payperpost.com/](https://payperpost.com/) [http://www.teliad.com/](http://www.teliad.com/)

Comment: Isn't this better suited to sister site http://freelancing.stackexchange.com/ -- or is it 6 vs half-dozen?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of market research it sounds like you have identified the niche that you want to target but have come up dry on what to do next.

Working with the information you have given me you seem to want to write about TV shows (nice choice) and need to find a buyer for those writings. The question is then who would buy such work?

Here I would suggest that the people buying such work would be "selling" it too. So I would want to find blogs, magazines or publications that specialize in TV shows. Adding in my own knowledge of this niche I know that there are genre specific sites - for example Sci-Fi has a lot of specialised publications.

So my search in Google would be for pages talking about the shows I think might have some milage. I would start with the most popular shows that you can think of as this will produce the most hits. Depending on the quality of the sites I find I might simply note some good sources or scale down to more specialised to reduce "noise" results.

Once you have a good list of sites that use the kind of content that you want to produce you would need to do what I would do which is to try and figure out if they take freelance stuff. If they do do they accept unsolicited work?

Unsolicited means that you speculatively submit the work and hope that they want it and will pay you.

Solicited means that you approach them with the idea and they commission the work if they like it.

In most cases you are probably going to have to approach the publication editors and ask them about freelance or non-staff writers. The best way to ask this is the subject for another question.

Finally you should have a list of publications and the way that the editors like to get writer leads (submissions or commissions). Then it is all down to you to make the sale.